# The Regalim and the Fasts

Tags: sources-mekorot, fast-days, chagim-holidays

Looking for resources --

Are there any texts which discuss the parallels between the 3 regalim and the 3 fast days in the cycle of the destruction of the Beit HaMikdash?

Off the top of my head, I can see parallels as follows:

1. The beginning of the path to matan torah on Pesach and the
   siege/beginning on the path to communal loss on Jerusalem on 10 Tevet
2. The building of walls on Sukkot and the breaching of walls on 17 Tammuz
3. The receiving of the Torah on Shavu'ot and the loss of the Beit Hamikdash on 9 Av

(I have yet to figure out how to add in Tzom Gedalyah...)

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: As you note there are 4 Temple-related fasts but only 3 regalim. Why look for a bijection?

Comment: One might argue that Shmini Atzeret is a regel on its own, I guess. Also, tzom gedalyah is separated from the process of destruction of the temple. It is related to the idea of exile, but not the destruction per se.